# validating deep fields in redux-from

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have wizard redux-from and my fields are something like this:

```js
<Field
    component={TextField}
    className="mui-textfield"
    floatingLabelText="title"
    name="data.title"
    fullWidth={true}
/>
```

so I want to validate the form with validate function,

**Question:**

how can I do this work?

Thanks

Comment: refer https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/wizard/

Comment: Thanks, I read that documentation and that does not solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, your error object is empty, so you can't set a nested key, since it's parent is undefined, you have to first define the data key, and then set the error on title inside the data.

You can do something like (Tweak the "!" or any other condition according to your needs)

```
validate(values)
{
    const errors = {}
    if (!values.data || (values.data && !values.data.title))
        errors.data = {title: "should exist"};
    return errors;
}
```